# Inhibit indentation of first paragraph of quotation

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs, quoting

I'm using LyX. Would it be possible to format something as "quotation" in a way in which the first paragraph doesn't get indented but the subsequent paragraphs does, like the way in which text formatted as "standard" in most classes doesn't indent first paragraphs?

I read somewhere than indentation of quotations is language specific but I've tried formatting the text as Danish, German and English with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried using `\noindent`?  I don't know if it's possible to write it on LyX, nor if it's possible to set a macro using it for the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package provides a consolidated environment for displayed text with control over first-line indentation. Without LyX, one simply doesn't add a blank line before the start of the environment and hereby prevents indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quoting}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\sometext
% <-- No indentation of first `quoting` line
\begin{quoting}
\sometext

\sometext
\end{quoting}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

With LyX it may be difficult to avoid "blank lines", but you may use the `indentfirst=false` option when adding the package to your LaTeX preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{quoting}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\begin{quoting}
\sometext

\sometext
\end{quoting}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

Output for both examples:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried adding '\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{quoting}' to the LaTeX preamble via the LyX settings but that doesn't change anything. Should I add anything else?

Comment: @Andreas I'm afraid that you'll also have to add `\begin{quoting}` and `\end{quoting}` at the appropriate locations in the document body (as LaTeX code/"evil red text").

Comment: @Andreas I'm not familiar with LyX, but it *may* be possible to add a new environment (here: `quoting`) to the ones available with the LyX interface.

Comment: Tried adding '\begin{quoting}' and '\end{quoting}' as ERT before and after the quotation but it isn't working. Thanks anyway - maybe I'll just stick with the default style for now ...

Comment: @Andreas Maybe the `quoting` package isn't included by default in your TeX distribution (TeXLive/MiKTeX) and must be installed.

Comment: @Andreas Also, please check the actual PDF output, not only the LyX preview.

Comment: I installed the package simple called texlive (in Linux Mint) which was described as containing TeX packages for most needs and reconfigured LyX. Anyways, nothing changed - not in the pdf output either ...

Comment: @Andreas I don't know if the TeX Live version of Linux Mint already includes `quoting`. Sorry that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It works - I just needed to remove the quotation formatting in LyX. Another problem appeared: now the quotation is as big as the other text and no longer affected by this in my preamble that makes other quotes and quotations smaller: '\let\oldquote\quote
\renewcommand\quote{\small\oldquote}
\let\oldquotation\quotation
\renewcommand\quotation{\small\oldquotation}' - any easy fix?

Comment: @Andreas Sure. :-) `\usepackage[indentfirst=false,font=small]{quoting}`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! What should I do forum-wise. Should I click "Answer Your Question" and add the answer(s) you gave me?

Comment: @Andreas No -- you should upvote my answer as "helpful" (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and accept it (by clicking on the checkmark). Please also upvote and possibly accept answers to your other questions at tex.sx.

Comment: @Andreas Also have a look at the [about](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) page.

Comment: @lockstep and Andreas: Regarding "I'm not familiar with LyX, but it may be possible to add a new environment". Yes, it's pretty easy but does require some reading. What you would want to do is make a module. See Help > Customization > 5.2 Types of layout files and 5.3 The layout file format. There are many examples to go off of.