# Inhibit indentation in paragraph after using the "quoting" package

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs, quoting

A little while ago I asked [this questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110213/inhibit-indentation-of-first-paragraph-of-quotation) concerning how to quote in the style of "quotation" but without the first paragraph being indented. The answer I got was to use the `quoting` package instead of `quotation`. It worked as it should ... I thought. Only now I've noticed that the first paragraph after my quote gets indented when I use `quoting` - and I don't want that.

Is there any way to use `quoting` and not having the following paragraph af standard text being indented as when you use `quote` or `quotation`? (BTW I'm using LyX)

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paragraph following a standard `quote` or `quotation` *is* indented (if the document class is using a non zero parindent.) Note that it is possible to have in-paragraph quotations where the following part paragraph is not indented, just by not having a blank line before or after the quote. If this is not the issue here, please edit your question to show a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: +1. Note that the `quoting` environment (of my package of the same name) works like `quote` and `quotation` with respect to indentation of following paragraphs; `quoting`'s additional mechanism deals with indentation of the environment's first paragraph.

Comment: I'm using the thesis template in LyX in which the first paragraph after `quote` and `quotation` isn't indented - it is after the quotes using the `quoting` package, though.

Comment: @Andreas Is lyx adding a blank line after the quoting environment? If it is then that starts a new paragraph and you get an indent. The same is true of `quote` so presumably lyx is not inserting a blank line in that case? Please post a complete example of generated latex that shows the problem.

Comment: That's it - LyX is adding a blank line if I make a new paragraph after `quoting`. The  trick is to insert `\begin{quoting}` and `\end{quoting}` as ERT within what then appears as one text block in the LyX GUI. Accepting answer.